# What's the difference between these two requirejs modules?

Tags: requirejs

Sorry if this seems an odd question, but I'm just start learning requirejs and some advanced javascript.

Both these modules work, so question is: what's the difference and why should I prefer the first/second way?

```js
// First way
define(['handlebars', 'backbone.marionette'], 
    function() {
        console.log(Handlebars, Backbone.Marionette); // Ok
    }
);

// Another way
define(['handlebars', 'backbone.marionette'], 
    function(Handlebars, BackboneMarionette) {
        console.log(Handlebars, BackboneMarionette); // Ok
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define(['handlebars', 'backbone.marionette'], 
    function() {
        console.log(Handlebars, Backbone.Marionette); // Ok
    }
);
```

the only reason this one works is you have handlebars and marionette existing in the window namespace already. So Handlebars, Backbone.Marionette are global values that exist outside your function definition. I.E :

```
console.log(Handlebars, Backbone.Marionette); // ok
define(['handlebars', 'backbone.marionette'], 
    function() {
        console.log(Handlebars, Backbone.Marionette); // Ok
    }
);
```

Comment: yes there is . in the second exemple Handlebars depends on the dependecy definition. in th first one it does not.